# Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /run/user/gui/spring (Errno::EACCES)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am having this issue while opening -> rails console

```
[chitra@localhost todo_app]$ rails c
/home/chitra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:252:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /run/user/gui/spring (Errno::EACCES)
    from /home/chitra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:252:in `fu_mkdir'
    from /home/chitra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:226:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from /home/chitra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `reverse_each'
    from /home/chitra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from /home/chitra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:210:in `each'
    from /home/chitra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:210:in `mkdir_p'
    from /home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@todo/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/env.rb:37:in `tmp_path'
    from /home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@todo/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/env.rb:54:in `pidfile_path'
    from /home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@todo/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/env.rb:69:in `server_running?'
    from /home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@todo/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:25:in `call'
    from /home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@todo/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@todo/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:24:in `call'
    from /home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@todo/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@todo/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'
    from /home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@todo/gems/spring-1.4.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@todo/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /home/chitra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@todo/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/projects/todo_app/bin/spring:13:in `require'
    from /opt/projects/todo_app/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I am using ruby version 2.2.0p0 and rails 4.2.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `sudo chown -R chitra /run/user/gui/spring`

Comment: After unsetting this, Issue gets fixed `unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`

Answer (score 6):

Here is the code that's throwing the error:

```
# File 'lib/spring/env.rb', line 35

def tmp_path
  path = Pathname.new(File.join(ENV['XDG_RUNTIME_DIR'] || Dir.tmpdir, "spring"))
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(path) unless path.exist?
  path
end
```

Looks like you have `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` set to `/run/user/gui/` but the server doesn't have write access to that directory.  So you can either grant access to that directory, or unset `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` by typing `unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`

Comment: Or to set it to be yours: `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=${id -u}`.